# Argo - what does mean arrow brackets in decode method?

Tags: ios, swift, argo

I try to master Argo for json decoding. In documentations there is example of decode function

```
extension User: Decodable {
  static func decode(j: JSON) -> Decoded<User> {
    return curry(User.init)
     <^> j <| "id"
     <*> j <| "name"
    }  
}
```

What does `<^>` and `<*>` mean ? What is the difference between them ?

Comment: I'd recommend https://github.com/Anviking/Decodable. I used Argo a bit but I think Decodable just does everything much cleaner ever since Swift added support for exceptions. Not as many weird operators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tldr, use `<^>` for the first parameter and use `<*>` for every parameter after that.

Long answer:
`<^>` is the same as Swift's `map` function. It's an operator borrowed from Haskell (a purely functional programming language). Although, in Haskell it's actually `<$>` but Swift cannot use `$` in its operators so we (and others in the community) chose `<^>` instead.

`<^>`, aka `map`, applies a function to a value inside a context. That context can be `Optional`, `Array`, `Dictionary`, or many others. In the context of `Optional`, `<^>` will apply the function in the first argument (left of the operator) to the optional value in the second argument (right side of the operator). The result will be `.none` if the optional value was `.none` or `.some(x)` where `x` is the result of the unwrapped optional value after it is passed into the function.

I hope that makes sense. If so, `<*>` isn't much different except that the function in the first argument is also wrapped in a context like `Optional`. So you have an `Optional` function and an `Optional` value, then you would use `<*>`. That is why we use `<*>` after we use `<^>` for the first time, because after the first `<^>`, `map`, we're left with a partially applied constructor (a function), that has been wrapped in a context by `<^>`.

`<*>` is taken from Haskell as well. In Haskell it is called `Applicative` and uses that exact same operator.

Answer (score 5):

According to the [Github documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/Argo/blob/master/Documentation/Functional-Concepts.md)...

`<^>` is the `map` function

and

`<*>` is the `apply` function

Both of these are described here... https://robots.thoughtbot.com/functional-swift-for-dealing-with-optional-values

Linked from the Github page.

N.B. Read the documentation :)